# Conflicting implementation error that only appears when type parameters are introduced (and disappears with helper trait)

Tags: rust

Below I define three traits.  For each trait, I

- implement on `&'a T` where `T` implements the trait
- implement on `&'a usize`.

In each case, however, I observe something slightly different.

### Case 1

For the trait `GetOneVer1` I observe no errors.

### Case 2

For the trait `GetOneVer2` I get an error:

```
conflicting implementations of trait `GetOneVer2<_>` for type `&usize`
downstream crates may implement trait `GetOneVer2<_>` for type `usize`rustcE0119
```

I think I understand this error -- the compiler is worried that in the future someone will implement the trait on `usize` and then that implementation will automatically extend to `&'a usize` because I implement the trait on `&'a T` where `T` implements the trait.  That means we could potentially have two competing implementations of the same trait.

### Case 3

For the trait `GetOneVer3` I get no error.  Note that this case is essentially identical to case 2.  The only difference is that, in this case, I define an extra trait "InheritTrait" and require that `T` implements `InheritTrait` in my implementation on `&'a T`.

## Questions

- Why does case 2 produce errors whereas cases 1 and 3 do not?  The only difference I see is that, in case 2, the trait has a generic type parameter, and in case 3 there are both a generic type parameter and a "helper" trait.
- There's a commented line in case 3 that auto-implements `InheritTrait` on immutable references.  Uncommenting this line produces no errors, and (I believe) achieves my ultimate goal of auto-implementing a trait on immutable references.  Will this method (using a helper trait that has no methods or type parameters) work to bypass the problem posed by case 2, in general, or are there other subtleties I should worry about?

```
//  ===============================================================================
//  TRAIT 1: NO ERROR
//  ===============================================================================

// define trait
pub trait GetOneVer1 {
    fn get_one(&self) -> usize;
}

// implement on &'a T, where T implements the trait
impl<'a, T: GetOneVer1> GetOneVer1 for &'a T {
    fn get_one(&self) -> usize {
        1
    }
}

// implement on &'a usize
impl<'a> GetOneVer1 for &'a usize {
    fn get_one(&self) -> usize {
        1
    }
}

//  ===============================================================================
//  TRAIT 2: ERROR
//  ===============================================================================

// define trait
pub trait GetOneVer2<Key> {
    fn get_one(&self, index: Key) -> usize;
}

// implement on &'a T, where T implements the trait
impl<'a, Key, T: GetOneVer2<Key>> GetOneVer2<Key> for &'a T {
    fn get_one(&self, index: Key) -> usize {
        1
    }
}

// implement on &'a usize
impl<'a, Key> GetOneVer2<Key> for &'a usize {
    fn get_one(&self, index: Key) -> usize {
        1
    }
}

//  ===============================================================================
//  TRAIT 3: NO ERROR (CORRECTED BY ADDING A SECOND TRAIT REQUIREMENT)
//  ===============================================================================

// define "helper trait"
pub trait InheritTrait {}
// impl<'a, T: InheritTrait> InheritTrait for &'a T {} // uncommenting this line does NOT produce any errors

// define trait
pub trait GetOneVer3<Key> {
    fn get_one(&self, index: Key) -> usize;
}

// implement on &'a T, where T implements the trait
impl<'a, Key, T: GetOneVer3<Key> + InheritTrait> GetOneVer3<Key> for &'a T {
    fn get_one(&self, index: Key) -> usize {
        1
    }
}

// implement on &'a usize
impl<'a, Key> GetOneVer3<Key> for &'a usize {
    fn get_one(&self, index: Key) -> usize {
        1
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why does case 2 produce errors whereas cases 1 and 3 do not? The only difference I see is that, in case 2, the trait has a generic type parameter, and in case 3 there are both a generic type parameter and a "helper" trait.

The generic parameter is *exactly* the problem.

Who can implement `GetOneVer1` for `usize`? Only you (who defined the trait) or the owner of `usize` (std).

Who can implement `GetOneVer2<Key>` for `usize` for some `Key`? You, `usize`'s owner, **or anyone who owns `Key`**. And since `Key` is generic, that means **everyone**.

[The orphan rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/implementations.html#orphan-rules) have not problems with a potential conflict between the owner of the trait and the owner of the type, because the compiler can see this impl does not exist (it depends only on **upstream** crates, std in this example). However, in the second case, **downstream** crates may implement it - and thus the compiler cannot prove this impl will not exist.

In the third case, we re-added the guarantee - as long as no `impl InheritTrait for usize` exists (which only you and std can provide), no trait can get the blanket implementation for references. Indeed, if you will add this impl, [the compiler will error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c8b69676ab49e1d0546ec37cc1693415).

> There's a commented line in case 3 that auto-implements InheritTrait on immutable references. Uncommenting this line produces no errors, and (I believe) achieves my ultimate goal of auto-implementing a trait on immutable references. Will this method (using a helper trait that has no methods or type parameters) work to bypass the problem posed by case 2, in general, or are there other subtleties I should worry about?

It will not work, because you still need `impl InheritTrait for usize`, and like we saw, this impl is impossible to write.